# "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I'm trying to move from sqlite to postgres so I can use Heroku. (Though this is error is occurring locally).

My `database.yml` currently looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_production
```

I have run `rake db:create db:migrate` but I get this error:

```
FATAL: database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
```

This is confusing given `db/development.sqlite3` no longer exists in `database.yml`. It was replaced by `db_development`. There's also no mention of `sqlite3` in my gem file.

**Edit:**

As per the suggestion below, `$ grep -rn 'development.sqlite3' *` returns:

```
log/development.log:3225:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3287:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3349:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3414:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3476:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3538:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3600:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3663:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3725:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3787:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3849:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3914:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:3976:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4038:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4100:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4162:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4224:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4287:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4349:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4411:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4477:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4539:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4605:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4667:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4729:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4791:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4853:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4915:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:4977:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5043:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5105:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5167:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5229:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5292:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5354:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5416:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5478:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5541:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5603:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5665:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5731:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5793:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5855:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5927:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:5989:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:6051:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:6113:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:6175:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:6237:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:6299:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
log/development.log:6361:ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "db/development.sqlite3" does not exist
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:101:    #  # => {pool: 5, timeout: 5000, database: "db/development.sqlite3", adapter: "sqlite3"}
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/core.rb:27:      #     database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/core.rb:38:      #         'database' => 'db/development.sqlite3'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.1.7/guides/source/configuring.md:613:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.1.7/guides/source/configuring.md:666:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.1.7/guides/source/configuring.md:922:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/jdbcsqlite3.yml:12:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/sqlite3.yml:14:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:101:    #  # => {pool: 5, timeout: 5000, database: "db/development.sqlite3", adapter: "sqlite3"}
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/core.rb:27:      #     database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/core.rb:38:      #         'database' => 'db/development.sqlite3'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rails-4.1.7/guides/source/configuring.md:613:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rails-4.1.7/guides/source/configuring.md:666:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rails-4.1.7/guides/source/configuring.md:922:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/jdbcsqlite3.yml:12:  database: db/development.sqlite3
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/sqlite3.yml:14:  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, the issue appears to be somewhere else.

Comment: Is there any other code I can provide that would be helpful?

Comment: If I knew, I would have suggested. Personally, I don't keep `database.yml` in repository at all since it's environment-specific data: Heroku has its `DATABASE_URL` that's looked up properly by Rails 4.1+. Huh... Can you publish a reproducible example of the same issue on Github?

Comment: Heroku will fill in the production section in a post commit hook - you should remove the production section form your YAML file to avoid confusion (as in confusing other programmers).

Comment: Did you check for the silly things? Like.. you did actually commit the yml file and pushed it, you did a `heroku restart`.. you tried `heroku rake db:reset`.. stuff like that..

Comment: @HarishVed, this error is obviously in the development environment. Heroku writes over the committed `database.yml` in a post commit hook anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. To clarify: this error is being thrown locally, not on Heroku.

Comment: Hack - try `grep -rn 'development.sqlite3' *` in your project root. You will know if its mentioned somewhere. Thanks @max , didn't know about [that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior).

Comment: Have you tried stopping and starting the server again? Probably pretty obvious but rails will only read the `database.yml` and other config files on startup - not on every request.

Comment: @max ah, that did it. Just needed a simple restart. Thanks.